# ReferenceError be is not defined in cypress

Tags: cypress

i am new to cypress, when using should(be.visible).click() getting
ReferenceError be is not defined in cypress
at Context.eval (webpack:///./cypress/integration/2-advanced-examples/loginnew.spec.js:14:66)

can you please help me and let me know what could be the issue?

Code I tried (from comment):

```js
describe('Login', function() { 
  it('should be able to login ', function() {
    expect(cy).property('xpath').to.be.a('function') 
    cy.get(input[data-with='Continue']).should(be.visible).click()
```

Comment: Please share your code that you tried.

Comment: describe('Login', function(){
        it('should be able to login ', function(){
            expect(cy).property('xpath').to.be.a('function')
            cy.get(`input[data-with='Continue']`).should(be.visible).click()

Answer (score 0):

You should be quoting things in the commands, like

```js
cy.get("input[data-with='Continue']")
  .should("be.visible")
  .click()
```